# ZipkinSpanReporter is not working properly

Tags: spring-cloud-netflix, zipkin, spring-cloud-sleuth

i am trying to evaluate zipkin to enable distributed tracing capability for all our micro-service. Below are versions in my setup.

1. Spring-boot version: **1.5.7.RELEASE**
2. spring-cloud version:
   **Camden.SR6**
3. zipkin version : **2.2.1**

   Configuration for seluth in `application.properties`

**spring.sleuth.sampler.percentage=1.0**

**spring.sleuth.web.skipPattern=(^cleanup.*|.+favicon.*)**

And i created the ZipkinSpanReporter bean as below. Note that I have setup the Eureka server as all micro services and even zipkin server registerred with Eureka server so that the Zipkin client can resolve zipkin server via eureka

```
 @Bean
    public ZipkinSpanReporter makeZipkinSpanReporter() {
        return new ZipkinSpanReporter() {
            private HttpZipkinSpanReporter delegate;
            private String baseUrl;

            @Override
            public void report(Span span) {

                InstanceInfo instance = eurekaClient
                        .getNextServerFromEureka("zipkin", false);
                if (!(baseUrl != null &&
                        instance.getHomePageUrl().equals(baseUrl))) {
                    baseUrl = instance.getHomePageUrl();
                    delegate = new HttpZipkinSpanReporter(baseUrl,
                            zipkinProperties.getFlushInterval(),
                            zipkinProperties.getCompression().isEnabled(),
                            spanMetricReporter);

                    if (!span.name.matches(skipPattern)) delegate.report(span);
                }
            }
        };
    }
```

What I have observered is that the zipkin client (book) is not reporting all spans back to zipkin server when I checked the zipkin. Some are reported, almost of spans are dropped

[image]

I have enabled the logging for

```
logging.level.org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web=DEBUG
logging.file=book.log
```

below are logging info:

```
2017-10-30 12:51:41.747 DEBUG [book,73fdabf29eb273f2,73fdabf29eb273f2,true] 14088 --- [http-nio-8888-exec-1] o.s.c.sleuth.instrument.web.TraceFilter  : No parent span present - creating a new span
2017-10-30 12:51:41.749 DEBUG [book,73fdabf29eb273f2,73fdabf29eb273f2,true] 14088 --- [http-nio-8888-exec-1] o.s.c.s.i.web.TraceHandlerInterceptor    : Handling span [Trace: 73fdabf29eb273f2, Span: 73fdabf29eb273f2, Parent: null, exportable:true]
2017-10-30 12:51:41.750 DEBUG [book,73fdabf29eb273f2,73fdabf29eb273f2,true] 14088 --- [http-nio-8888-exec-1] o.s.c.s.i.web.TraceHandlerInterceptor    : Adding a method tag with value [checkedOut] to a span [Trace: 73fdabf29eb273f2, Span: 73fdabf29eb273f2, Parent: null, exportable:true]
2017-10-30 12:51:41.750 DEBUG [book,73fdabf29eb273f2,73fdabf29eb273f2,true] 14088 --- [http-nio-8888-exec-1] o.s.c.s.i.web.TraceHandlerInterceptor    : Adding a class tag with value [BookApplication] to a span [Trace: 73fdabf29eb273f2, Span: 73fdabf29eb273f2, Parent: null, exportable:true]
2017-10-30 12:51:41.752 DEBUG [book,73fdabf29eb273f2,73fdabf29eb273f2,true] 14088 --- [http-nio-8888-exec-1] o.s.c.sleuth.instrument.web.TraceFilter  : Closing the span [Trace: 73fdabf29eb273f2, Span: 73fdabf29eb273f2, Parent: null, exportable:true] since the response was successful
2017-10-30 12:51:42.133 DEBUG [book,,,] 14088 --- [http-nio-8888-exec-1] o.s.c.sleuth.instrument.web.TraceFilter  : Received a request to uri [/favicon.ico] that should not be sampled [true]
2017-10-30 12:51:42.134 DEBUG [book,9e7aab2fdb2313a9,9e7aab2fdb2313a9,false] 14088 --- [http-nio-8888-exec-1] o.s.c.sleuth.instrument.web.TraceFilter  : No parent span present - creating a new span
2017-10-30 12:51:42.142 DEBUG [book,9e7aab2fdb2313a9,9e7aab2fdb2313a9,false] 14088 --- [http-nio-8888-exec-1] o.s.c.sleuth.instrument.web.TraceFilter  : Closing the span [Trace: 9e7aab2fdb2313a9, Span: 9e7aab2fdb2313a9, Parent: null, exportable:false] since the response was successful
2017-10-30 12:52:05.167 DEBUG [book,,,] 14088 --- [http-nio-8888-exec-2] o.s.c.sleuth.instrument.web.TraceFilter  : Received a request to uri [/checked-out] that should not be sampled [false]
2017-10-30 12:52:05.168 DEBUG [book,05274e0bdf3038b9,05274e0bdf3038b9,true] 14088 --- [http-nio-8888-exec-2] o.s.c.sleuth.instrument.web.TraceFilter  : No parent span present - creating a new span
2017-10-30 12:52:05.171 DEBUG [book,05274e0bdf3038b9,05274e0bdf3038b9,true] 14088 --- [http-nio-8888-exec-2] o.s.c.s.i.web.TraceHandlerInterceptor    : Handling span [Trace: 05274e0bdf3038b9, Span: 05274e0bdf3038b9, Parent: null, exportable:true]
2017-10-30 12:52:05.171 DEBUG [book,05274e0bdf3038b9,05274e0bdf3038b9,true] 14088 --- [http-nio-8888-exec-2] o.s.c.s.i.web.TraceHandlerInterceptor    : Adding a method tag with value [checkedOut] to a span [Trace: 05274e0bdf3038b9, Span: 05274e0bdf3038b9, Parent: null, exportable:true]
2017-10-30 12:52:05.172 DEBUG [book,05274e0bdf3038b9,05274e0bdf3038b9,true] 14088 --- [http-nio-8888-exec-2] o.s.c.s.i.web.TraceHandlerInterceptor    : Adding a class tag with value [BookApplication] to a span [Trace: 05274e0bdf3038b9, Span: 05274e0bdf3038b9, Parent: null, exportable:true]
2017-10-30 12:52:05.174 DEBUG [book,05274e0bdf3038b9,05274e0bdf3038b9,true] 14088 --- [http-nio-8888-exec-2] o.s.c.sleuth.instrument.web.TraceFilter  : Closing the span [Trace: 05274e0bdf3038b9, Span: 05274e0bdf3038b9, Parent: null, exportable:true] since the response was successful
2017-10-30 12:52:05.589 DEBUG [book,,,] 14088 --- [http-nio-8888-exec-2] o.s.c.sleuth.instrument.web.TraceFilter  : Received a request to uri [/favicon.ico] that should not be sampled [true]
2017-10-30 12:52:05.589 DEBUG [book,b891d03ce6bccdf4,b891d03ce6bccdf4,false] 14088 --- [http-nio-8888-exec-2] o.s.c.sleuth.instrument.web.TraceFilter  : No parent span present - creating a new span
2017-10-30 12:52:05.594 DEBUG [book,b891d03ce6bccdf4,b891d03ce6bccdf4,false] 14088 --- [http-nio-8888-exec-2] o.s.c.sleuth.instrument.web.TraceFilter  : Closing the span [Trace: b891d03ce6bccdf4, Span: b891d03ce6bccdf4, Parent: null, exportable:false] since the response was successful
```

But I could not be able to find the traceId which is logged in `book.log` file from zipkin console

Could you please explain why many spans are not reported to zipkin server?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi! You are using Camden. Currently, we have Dalston.SR4 release. Please upgrade the release train and see if you still have any problems

Comment: I have updated to the Dalston.SR4 but the situation even worse as I can not see things reported on Zipkin dashboard. @MarcinGrzejszczak

Can you adivise which versions of spring cloud compatible with zipkin 2.2.1

Comment: Please upload the sample somewhere. This feature is known to be working fine (at least nobody has ever said that it's not). From what you write in the issue, the logs suggest that everything gets exported other than the `favicon` resource. You provide too little information to help you at this point.

Comment: unfortunely, I am in office so I am not able to upload code outside, I tried to enble debug logging level in zipkin server to see whether zipkin client posted traces to server or not. However I can not see any logging info from server that I supposed server has not recieved any logging info from client.
`logging.level.zipkin.server=DEBUG`

`logging.file=zipkin.log` @MarcinGrzejszczak

Comment: If you remove your custom `ZipkinSpanReporter` - does it work as it should?

Comment: after moving to custom `ZipkinSpanReporter`  bean,  it is working perfectly now. have you got any idea why custom bean causing problem? @MarcinGrzejszczak

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it correct that you are using the code example from the baeldung tutorial? (http://www.baeldung.com/tracing-services-with-zipkin - 3.2. Spring Config)

I think there is a mistake with line 34 and 35 (the closing curly brace).

I've fixed the problem by modifing the method like this:

```
@Bean
public ZipkinSpanReporter makeZipkinSpanReporter() {
    return new ZipkinSpanReporter() {
        private HttpZipkinSpanReporter delegate;
        private String baseUrl;

        @Override
        public void report(Span span) {

            InstanceInfo instance = eurekaClient
                    .getNextServerFromEureka("zipkin", false);
            if (!(baseUrl != null &&
                    instance.getHomePageUrl().equals(baseUrl))) {
                baseUrl = instance.getHomePageUrl();
                RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
                zipkinRestTemplateCustomizer.customize(restTemplate);
                delegate = new HttpZipkinSpanReporter(
                        restTemplate,
                        baseUrl,
                        zipkinProperties.getFlushInterval(),
                        spanMetricReporter);
            }

            if (!span.name.matches(skipPattern)) {
                delegate.report(span);
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Maybe this helps someone or maybe someone from baeldung reads this and could verify and correct the code example. ;)

Comment: yes, I used your reference for setting up zipkin, thanks for your fix.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely your code is broken. You can check out the https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-sleuth/blob/master/spring-cloud-sleuth-zipkin/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/sleuth/zipkin/ZipkinAutoConfiguration.java class where for Edgware we've added load balanced zipkin server resolution.

Comment: Thanks @Marcin I have checked code but wondering how can I get the baseUrl from eureka to resolve the zipkin servers from client as I dont want to configure the baseUrl to a particular server

`@ConfigurationProperties("spring.zipkin")
public class ZipkinProperties {
 /** URL of the zipkin query server instance. */
 private String baseUrl = "http://localhost:9411/";`

Comment: Please read the docs - http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-sleuth/1.3.0.RC1/multi/multi__sending_spans_to_zipkin.html

Comment: you are referring to version `1.3.0.RC1`  of **spring-cloud-sleuth** but I am using the  `1.2.5.RELEASE` version. so that is why it is not working with virtual host via eureka. Thanks for  your tremendious support @Marcin

Comment: Indeed, using release train `Edgware.RC1` of Spring Cloud (together with Spring Boot `1.5.6.RELEASE`) the Zipkin server host name is resolved using Eureka service registry. No custom `ZipkinSpanReporter` required. Required properties are `spring.zipkin.locator.discovery.enabled: true` and `spring.zipkin.baseUrl: http://zipkinserver/`.